# Which characters are allowed in your name?

Tags: steam, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

When I changed my name on Steam, I noticed that some characters are not supported and will display in game but are not allowed to have as a name in Steam. So my questions is: which characters are you allowed to use in your name in-game in MW3?

Comment: Is this question about Modern Warfare or Steam or both? Seams like Steam to me.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can use ISO-8859-1 and utf-8.
Here is what you can use in Steam (based on another forum):
http://www.yellowpipe.com/yis/tools/ALT-Characters/

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering witch characters Modern Warefare accepts

Comment: UTF-8 can encode the entire Unicode range of characters, so writing "UTF-8" is like writing "there's no restriction on anything". I don't think that's what you meant to write.